# Python tornado has a big time difference between the request from the client and the execution of the view

Tags: python, tornado

I use tornado framework to build a web server, but I have encountered some problems. There is a big time difference between the request from the client and the execution of the view. What should I do?
I did some debugging and recorded the time:

client request code like this:

```
begin_time = datetime.now()
req_id = uuid.uuid4().hex
try:
    resp = requests.post(url, json={'req_id': req_id}, timeout=5).json()
except Exception:
    pass

print(f"req_id: {req_id}, request_time: {begin_time}, resp_time: {datetime.now()}")
```

server code like this:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def __init__(self, *argc, **argkw):
            self.init_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            super(BaseHandler, self).__init__(*argc, **argkw)

class HeartbeatDetect(BaseHandler):
    SUPPORTED_METHODS = ("POST", "GET")

    async def post(self):
        req_id = self.qdict['req_id']
        logging.info(f'************init_time:{self.init_time}, view_time: 
        {datetime.datetime.now()} request coming: {self.qdict} req_id: {req_id}')
        ..... do something
```

The last recorded time is like this:

```
init_time   : 2021-11-15 10:01:20.353389
view_time   : 2021-11-15 10:01:22.288460
request_time: 2021-11-15 10:01:11
resp_time   : 2021-11-15 10:01:16
```

There is a difference of 9 seconds between the client `request_time` and the server `init_time`

I don’t know why this happens, can anyone help me? I am very grateful!

Comment: The client and the server are running in different processing, right?

Comment: @xyres The client code is a script that is executed regularly, and it is a function of heartbeat detection. The above code is partly taken from the production service;I don't know why this happens; At 2021-11-15 10:01 this minute, the request volume is 3231

Comment: It's hard to tell. I can't reproduce this behaviour on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Subclassess should not override `__init__` override `RequestHandler.initialize` instead.